# How to use resolve error due to backticks in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I started learning Angular today. While creating a component, I'm getting the following error, which has possibly to do something with the backticks.

```
              Error: src/app/app.component.ts:9:3 - error NG5002: Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'.

              9   `
                  ~


              Error: src/app/app.component.ts:9:3 - error NG5002: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? 
              Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)

              9   `
                  ~
```

The code for the component is as follows :

```
           import { Component } from "@angular/core";

           @Component({
             selector : 'pm-root',
             template : `
             <div><h1>{pageTitle}</h1>
            <div>My First Component</div>
            </div>
            `
            })
           export class AppComponent {
             pageTitle : string = 'Acme Product Management';
           }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to double up on the curly brackets: `{{pageTitle}}`.

Comment: Yes, it worked.